# Connect to Teamcity to OCI Autonomous Transaction Processing Database

Tags: oracle, jdbc, teamcity, oracle-call-interface, oracle19c

I am trying to migrate my Teamcity database from internal to external, and I registered a free tier ATP database. I am not sure how to how to set the connection URL in the teamcity database property files to access the database.

The tnsnames I am referencing is from the following:

```
teamcitytestdb_medium = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=rhhea6hkgj2saju_teamcitytestdb_medium.atp.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adwc.uscom-east-1.oraclecloud.com,OU=Oracle BMCS US,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Redwood City,ST=California,C=US")))
```

The command I ran for the tests below are using this command:

```
bin/maintainDB.sh migrate -T $(pwd)/database.oracle.autodb.properties.dist
```

Here is a list of commands and output I tried:

Test1:

```
connectionUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//adb.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com:1522/rhhea6hkgj2saju_teamcitytestdb_high.atp.oraclecloud.com
driverName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
connectionProperties.user=<username>
connectionProperties.password=<password>

--------- output ---------
Cannot proceed with 'migrate' command: Could not connect to the target database: Could not connect to Oracle server.
IO Error: Got minus one from a read call: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call. Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Got minus one from a read call
```

Test2:

```
connectionUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcps://adb.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com:1522/rhhea6hkgj2saju_teamcitytestdb_high.atp.oraclecloud.com?wallet_location=/Users/jiuwang/Documents/Spectra/3rd-jars/teamcity-tests/Wallet_TeamCityTestDB
driverName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
connectionProperties.user=<username>
connectionProperties.password=<password>

--------- output ---------
Cannot proceed with 'migrate' command: Could not connect to the target database: Could not connect to Oracle server.
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection. Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Test3:

```
connectionUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@adb.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com:1522:rhhea6hkgj2saju_teamcitytestdb_medium.atp.oraclecloud.com
driverName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
connectionProperties.user=<username>
connectionProperties.password=<password>

--------- output ---------
Cannot proceed with 'migrate' command: Could not connect to the target database: Could not connect to Oracle server.
IO Error: Got minus one from a read call: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call. Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Got minus one from a read call
```

How should I setup this correctly so the migration tool can connect to the database? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea about teamcity, but to connect to your ATP, you need to configure your jdbc env for the driver to know where to get the wallet, Look at this page https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-5ED3C08C-1A84-4E5A-B07A-A5114951AA9E

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the TNS_ADMIN to point to the path where you have downloaded the wallet credentials to connect to Autonomous Database.
Also, the JDBC version is important. You can use pass TNS_ADMIN as part of the connection URL only if you are using JDBC driver version 18.3 and above.

I would suggest to try a [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) to make sure if the connection works.

```
DB_URL ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@wallet_dbname?TNS_ADMIN=/Users/test/wallet_dbname";
```

Also, refer to this [page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/java-connectivity-to-atp.html) for more details.

Comment: I have tried this in my connectionURL settings, but it seemed like the teamcity connection properties does not support the `TNS_ADMIN` notation

Comment: What is the JDBC version and JDK version that you are using?